# where does window.somedata gets stored

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JavaScript when i say `window.SomeData = 'whatever'`, where does it get saved in the browser? I thought it gets saved in the `viewstate` but it doesnt. Also how much security concern is it to save some data in `window.someKey`. I am not talking about username or password storage but some general data like PK values of some records.

--Edit--

The reason i am asking this is because i have a page with 5 tabs and each tabs gets loaded by an AJAX call. I need to save the data that comes back from AJAX request and currently i am using window.somekey to save it.

Comment: What do you mean with viewstate btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets saved in the global object `window`. That object is not very secure and its lifetime is for that page.

Comment: what is the better solution if i have a page with 5 tabs and i want to keep the data while user is on the page and navigates between tabs?

Comment: @Asdfg You'd have to store that data in a cookie (or html5 localstorage I guess) or persist it to the server.

Comment: well, data is big for a cookie to save and i am not using html5 so i guess i have to live with window.someKey.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't get saved anywhere, it is exactly the same as using a global variable:

`var SomeData = "whatever"; //done in global scope obviously`

```
window.SomeData === "whatever" //true
```

Comment: at least it is available as long as user is on the page so it does save it for time-being.

Comment: @Asdfg well in a sense if you can call variables holding values saving... but you can save them for real using `localStorage` (up to 5mb) for example

Comment: looks like i made a mistake in describing the question. Data that i am storing in the window.someKey is indeed a variable that holds PK value or it may hold an Object that represents the data in the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere, effectively. Data stored in random fields of the `window` object is not saved.

Answer (score 0):

The annoying answer is its saved in memory!  Its no different than having

```
var j = {}
j.SomeData = 'Whatever'
```

`window` is just a global variable containing all the information about window (such as the documents DOM)

`window` can have data saved like the `j` variable above.  Its no less safe than saving any piece of information ANYWHERE else in js.  The only risk you have is that the items namespace may be used by another library.

So if i were you i would do this.  (use this as a guide to writing good JS http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/)

```
(function(MyLibrary, $, undefined) {
    var stuff;
    MyLibrary.SomeData = 5;
}(window.MyLibrary = window.MyLibrary || {}, jQuery)); // or moo tools

alert(window.MyLibrary.SomeData); // 5!
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally good practice to use an object as namespace for functions and variables specific for web application. For example:

```
var site = {};

site.someData = 'whatever';

site.initGallery = function() {
    //
};
```

Declaration of variables in global namespace (in client-side JS, `window` is global namespace) is called global-namespace pollution and is generally undesirable and unrecommended since it can lead to naming conflicts either with other libraries that also pollute global namespace or, even worse, with browser's native global objects.